# How to get Debugging Symbols when using yum on Fedora?

Tags: debugging, gdb, fedora, debug-symbols, cyrus

I'm trying to run Cyrus Imapd (version 2.3.1) in gdb on Fedora Core 5. I've installed cyrus imapd using yum install cyrus-imapd.  Does anyone know the correct way to get debugging symbols for this program? (I'm very aware that Fedora Core 5 and version 2.3.1 of cyrus imapd are outdated, but I'm in need of running that particular version in gdb).

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

"Fedora Core 5" is really out of date so there are probably no existing repositories providing debug symbols for your release version. So there are few possible solutions:

- Update or rather reinstall to *current* Fedora 23 and install package `cyrus-imapd-debuginfo` (preferably `sudo dnf debuginfo-install cyrus-imapd`)
- Download the [git repository](http://pkgs.fedoraproject.org/cgit/cyrus-imapd.git/) of the Fedora package, check to Fedora 5 tag and build the package yourself with debuginfo, but you will probably run into missing dependencies and you would end up with building really long chain of outdated dependencies.

Latest available build in [koji](http://koji.fedoraproject.org/koji/buildinfo?buildID=3421) I am able to find is for Fedora Core 7, but maybe it will work for you  (you would have to download and install the new version with debuginfo sub-package).